# segfault when accessing static std::map

Tags: c++11, dictionary, static

I'm trying to refactor a rather complicated piece of code and run into segfaults during loading the library. This is a minimal example of what I could single out to be the source of the segfault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Manager {
public:
  class Action{
  };
  static bool registerAction(const Action* a, const char* name);
};

namespace Actions {
  class ExampleAction : public Manager::Action {
  };
  namespace {
    static bool available = Manager::registerAction(new ExampleAction(),"ExampleAction");
  }
}

namespace {
  typedef std::map<const std::string,const Manager::Action*> ActionList;
  static ActionList sActions;
}

bool Manager::registerAction(const Action* a, const char* name){
  std::cout << "attempting to register action " << a << " as " << name << std::endl;
  sActions[name] = a;
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return true;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl;
  for(auto it:sActions){
    std::cout << it.first << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine with g++ 4.8.4 using the `--std=c++11` flag, but upon execution, this happens:

```
attempting to register action 0x1ebe010 as ExampleAction
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The line `attempting to register` comes first, which is of course expected, but the line assigning the value to the static map instance causes the crash, and I don't understand the reason. I'm probably being stupid here, but still - any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like an initialization order issue: `available` is initialized before `sActions`, and therefore `registerAction` operates on a non-initialized object `sActions`.

Comment: That might well be, thanks for spotting this. How could I change the order of initialization?

Comment: IMHO, it is better not to rely on the order and implement one of the solutions to the "static initialization order fiasco". The most common one probably is to wrap `sActions` in a function, e.g. `ActionList& getActions() { static ActionList sActions; return sActions; }` (for the static init order fiasco, an inline function is used) The function-scope static variable will be initialized at first use.

Comment: This solved it. Thanks a lot!